# In Flutter, how can I make a simple Browser widget with a WebView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I attempted to write a widget that would eventually have some functionality of a browser in Flutter. Already I ran into a roadblock trying to figure out how to tell it to load a URL. Here is what I have so far:

```dart
class Browser extends StatefulWidget {

  Browser({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  void loadUrl(String u, BuildContext ctx) {
    var s = getState(ctx);
    s.setState(() {
      s.home = Uri.parse(u);
      s.wvc?.loadUrl(u);
    });
  }

  static _BrowserState getState(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType();
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _BrowserState();
  }
}

class _BrowserState extends State<Browser> {
  WebView wv;
  WebViewController wvc;
  Uri home;

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.wv = WebView(
      initialUrl: '',
      debuggingEnabled: true,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController c) {
        this.wvc = c;
        if (home != null) {
          this.wvc.loadUrl(home.toString());
        }
      },
    );

    var expandedWebView = Expanded(child: this.wv);
    var c = new Container(
        child: new Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[expandedWebView])));
    return c;
  }
}
```

The problem is that in the various places I want to call the `loadUrl` method on the `Browser` widget, I don't have a `BuildContext` handy to pass in.

So I am about to give up on this approach and just write all of it as one big widget tree within the homepage. Which is too bad, because I think having this browser class would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the broader question of how to approach this, I got better results by using the singleton web view of [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) than by using webview_flutter. The flutter_webview_plugin is easy to set up in a way that behaves well, specifically: it doesn't constantly rebuild the widget, and it has good support for setting up as a browser.